# Imported BT App`s won`t run on my eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, buzztouch

While starting my app in emulator i got this error on eclipse

**ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.fmvsample/.BT_activity_root }**

then in  my emulator an error pop up message will occur saying

**Something is not right.
There was a problem loading the app`s configuration data. See logCat Console putput in Eclipse..**

In my .logs this is inserted.

**!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2013-10-23 08:55:25.345
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\jfalcutela'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.**

LogCat

**GC_EXPLICIT freed 116K, 5% free 15899K/16711K, paused 3ms+10ms**

I add image snapshot of the error when launching my app.

[IMAGE SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPA9.jpg)

Logcat output

```
10-23 10:57:26.771: D/AndroidRuntime(462): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-23 10:57:26.771: D/AndroidRuntime(462): CheckJNI is ON
10-23 10:57:27.321: D/AndroidRuntime(462): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
10-23 10:57:27.511: D/dalvikvm(281): GC_EXPLICIT freed 25K, 5% free 8634K/9027K, paused 5ms+2ms
10-23 10:57:27.511: W/ActivityManager(66): No content provider found for: 
10-23 10:57:27.714: W/ActivityManager(66): No content provider found for: 
10-23 10:57:27.731: D/PackageParser(66): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl-1227942713.tmp
10-23 10:57:28.221: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1630K, 19% free 13912K/16967K, paused 9ms+12ms
10-23 10:57:28.321: I/PackageManager(66): Removing non-system package:com.fmvsample
10-23 10:57:28.321: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package com.fmvsample uid=10038
10-23 10:57:28.341: I/Process(66): Sending signal. PID: 420 SIG: 9
10-23 10:57:28.451: I/WindowManager(66): WIN DEATH: Window{40fcf618 com.fmvsample/com.fmvsample.BT_activity_root paused=false}
10-23 10:57:28.671: D/dalvikvm(144): GC_EXPLICIT freed 63K, 7% free 14552K/15495K, paused 3ms+4ms
10-23 10:57:28.901: D/PackageManager(66): Scanning package com.fmvsample
10-23 10:57:28.901: I/PackageManager(66): Package com.fmvsample codePath changed from /data/app/com.fmvsample-1.apk to /data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
10-23 10:57:28.911: I/PackageManager(66): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk
10-23 10:57:28.981: D/installd(33): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk' ---
10-23 10:57:29.991: D/dalvikvm(471): DexOpt: load 47ms, verify+opt 558ms
10-23 10:57:30.073: D/installd(33): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk' (success) ---
10-23 10:57:30.073: W/PackageManager(66): Code path for pkg : com.fmvsample changing from /data/app/com.fmvsample-1.apk to /data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk
10-23 10:57:30.073: W/PackageManager(66): Resource path for pkg : com.fmvsample changing from /data/app/com.fmvsample-1.apk to /data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk
10-23 10:57:30.073: D/PackageManager(66):   Services: com.fmvsample.GCMIntentService
10-23 10:57:30.073: D/PackageManager(66):   Receivers: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver
10-23 10:57:30.073: D/PackageManager(66):   Activities: com.fmvsample.BT_activity_root com.fmvsample.BT_activity_base com.fmvsample.BT_activity_root_tabs com.fmvsample.BT_screen_customHTML com.fmvsample.BT_screen_menuListSimple
10-23 10:57:30.073: D/PackageManager(66):   Permissions: com.fmvsample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
10-23 10:57:30.091: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package com.fmvsample uid=10038
10-23 10:57:30.467: I/installd(33): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.fmvsample-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.fmvsample-2.apk@classes.dex
10-23 10:57:30.471: D/PackageManager(66): New package installed in /data/app/com.fmvsample-2.apk
10-23 10:57:30.501: W/PackageManager(66): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
10-23 10:57:30.521: W/PackageManager(66): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
10-23 10:57:30.521: W/PackageManager(66): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x8be44)
10-23 10:57:30.531: W/PackageManager(66): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.WRITE_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
10-23 10:57:30.541: W/PackageManager(66): Unknown permission com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL in package com.android.settings
10-23 10:57:30.552: W/PackageManager(66): Unknown permission android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA in package com.android.email
10-23 10:57:30.561: W/PackageManager(66): Unknown permission com.android.providers.im.permission.READ_ONLY in package com.google.android.apps.maps
10-23 10:57:30.561: W/PackageManager(66): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
10-23 10:57:30.891: I/ActivityManager(66): Force stopping package com.fmvsample uid=10038
10-23 10:57:30.981: D/dalvikvm(158): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 7% free 8909K/9543K, paused 5ms+3ms
10-23 10:57:31.101: D/PackageManager(66): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
10-23 10:57:31.111: D/PackageManager(66): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
10-23 10:57:31.111: D/dalvikvm(213): GC_EXPLICIT freed 119K, 5% free 9147K/9543K, paused 3ms+6ms
10-23 10:57:31.151: I/AccountTypeManager(213): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 5ms
10-23 10:57:31.191: D/PackageManager(66): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 3 services unchanged
10-23 10:57:31.211: I/AccountTypeManager(213): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 5ms
10-23 10:57:31.241: D/PackageManager(66): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 5 services unchanged
10-23 10:57:31.302: W/RecognitionManagerService(66): no available voice recognition services found
10-23 10:57:31.731: D/dalvikvm(66): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1755K, 24% free 12956K/16967K, paused 4ms+9ms
10-23 10:57:31.769: I/installd(33): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.fmvsample-1.apk@classes.dex
10-23 10:57:31.771: D/AndroidRuntime(462): Shutting down VM
10-23 10:57:31.791: D/dalvikvm(462): GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 84% free 331K/2048K, paused 1ms+0ms
10-23 10:57:31.791: D/jdwp(462): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
10-23 10:57:31.791: D/dalvikvm(462): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-23 10:57:31.829: I/AndroidRuntime(462): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-23 10:57:32.371: D/AndroidRuntime(476): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
10-23 10:57:32.371: D/AndroidRuntime(476): CheckJNI is ON
10-23 10:57:32.881: D/AndroidRuntime(476): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
10-23 10:57:32.911: I/ActivityManager(66): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.fmvsample/.BT_activity_root } from pid 476
10-23 10:57:32.931: I/ActivityManager(66): Start proc com.fmvsample for activity com.fmvsample/.BT_activity_root: pid=484 uid=10038 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
10-23 10:57:32.971: D/AndroidRuntime(476): Shutting down VM
10-23 10:57:32.991: D/dalvikvm(476): GC_CONCURRENT freed 112K, 83% free 358K/2048K, paused 0ms+1ms
10-23 10:57:32.991: D/dalvikvm(476): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-23 10:57:33.031: I/AndroidRuntime(476): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-23 10:57:33.692: W/ZZ(484): fmvsample_appDelegate: onCreate
10-23 10:57:33.692: W/ZZ(484): fmvsample_appDelegate:loadAudioPlayer
10-23 10:57:33.711: W/ZZ(484): BT_application: Creating root-app object.
10-23 10:57:33.721: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: Creating root-device object.
10-23 10:57:33.841: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: This device uses an Android display density of: 240dpi (dots per inch)
10-23 10:57:33.841: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: This device can take pictures.
10-23 10:57:33.851: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: This device can take videos.
10-23 10:57:33.851: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: This device can send emails.
10-23 10:57:33.881: W/ZZ(484): BT_device: This device is GPS capable.
10-23 10:57:33.881: W/ZZ(484): BT_user: Creating root-user object.
10-23 10:57:34.011: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:onCreate
10-23 10:57:34.161: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:loadAppData
10-23 10:57:34.211: W/ZZ(484): BT_device:updateDeviceConnectionType: ConnectionType: CELL
10-23 10:57:34.211: W/ZZ(484): BT_device:updateDeviceSize This device has a screen size of: 480 (width) x 800 (height).
10-23 10:57:34.211: W/ZZ(484): BT_device:updateDeviceSize This application considers this to be a "small device"
10-23 10:57:34.211: W/ZZ(484): BT_device:updateDeviceSize This device is in "landscape" orientation.
10-23 10:57:34.211: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:loadAppData loading BT_config.txt from /assests folder in Eclipse project...
10-23 10:57:34.501: W/ZZ(484): fmvsample_appDelegate:SoundEffectLoader:doInBackground initSoundEffects
10-23 10:57:34.501: W/ZZ(484): fmvsample_appDelegate:SoundEffectLoader:doInBackground initSoundEffects DISABLED
10-23 10:57:34.761: W/ZZ(484): BT_fileManager: readTextFileFromAssets: "/BT_config.txt"
10-23 10:57:34.771: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:loadAppData loaded BT_config.txt from /assets folder successfully...
10-23 10:57:34.771: W/ZZ(484): BT_application: getDataURLFromAppData
10-23 10:57:34.801: W/ZZ(484): BT_application:parseJSONData JSONObject ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1595 of {"BT_appConfig": {   "BT_items":[        {"itemId":"JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310",          "itemType":"BT_app",            "buzztouchAppId":"JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310",           "buzztouchAPIKey":"66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48",            "dataURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=getAppData&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37",           "reportToCloudURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=reportToCloud&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37&deviceId=[deviceId]&deviceLatitude=[deviceLatitude]&deviceLongitude=[deviceLongitude]&deviceModel=[deviceModel]&userId=[userId]",           "registerForPushURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=registerForPush&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37&deviceId=[deviceId]&deviceLatitude=[deviceLatitude]&deviceLongitude=[deviceLongitude]&deviceModel=[deviceModel]&userId=[userId]",           "lastModified":"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 07:13:40 -0700",           "lastPublished":"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 07:13:40 -0700",          "name":"FMV",           "version":"1.0",            "currentMode":"Design",             "startLocationUpdates":"0",             "promptForPushNotifications":"0",           "allowRotation":"allDevices",           "BT_themes":[{"itemId":"0022CEA6F2649E6360C8C3D", "itemType":"BT_theme", "backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"}           ],          "BT_tabs":[         ],          "BT_menus":[{"itemId":"2D2C9F150541A76A51C5386", "itemType":"BT_menu", "itemNickname":"Jhonathan" ,"childItems":[{"itemId":"FE26D928B5504FC39ADF8B1", "itemType":"BT_menuItem", "titleText":"Jhonathan Hfghgfhfgh""loadScreenWithItemId":"C7B140DD1E263F760276BEE"}]}           ],          "BT_screens":[{"itemId":"1ACCE0FA6AE0B2F69774E64", "itemType":"BT_screen_menuListSimple", "itemNickname":"Home Screen Menu", "navBarTitleText":"Home","childItems":[]},                 {"itemId":"C7B140DD1E263F760276BEE", "itemType":"BT_screen_customHTML", "itemNickname":"hfghggfhgfhfhfhgfh", "navBarTitleText":"hfghggfhgfhfhfhgfh"}            ]       }       ]   }}
10-23 10:57:34.801: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:loadAppData BT_config.txt file does not use a dataURL for remote updates...
10-23 10:57:34.801: W/ZZ(484): BT_fileManager:deleteFile cachedAppConfig.txt
10-23 10:57:34.801: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root:loadAppData continuing to load with BT_config.txt data in Eclipse project...
10-23 10:57:34.801: W/ZZ(484): BT_application: validateApplicationData
10-23 10:57:34.832: W/ZZ(484): BT_application:validateApplicationData EXCEPTION trying to parse JSON data? ERROR: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1595 of {"BT_appConfig": {   "BT_items":[        {"itemId":"JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310",          "itemType":"BT_app",            "buzztouchAppId":"JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310",           "buzztouchAPIKey":"66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48",            "dataURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=getAppData&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37",           "reportToCloudURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=reportToCloud&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37&deviceId=[deviceId]&deviceLatitude=[deviceLatitude]&deviceLongitude=[deviceLongitude]&deviceModel=[deviceModel]&userId=[userId]",           "registerForPushURL":"https://www.buzztouch.com/api/app/?command=registerForPush&appGuid=JAC2B9524B4D693E5FD245310&apiKey=66D126DB368EB7438DCAE48&apiSecret=7EF956D33C475675D162A37&deviceId=[deviceId]&deviceLatitude=[deviceLatitude]&deviceLongitude=[deviceLongitude]&deviceModel=[deviceModel]&userId=[userId]",           "lastModified":"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 07:13:40 -0700",           "lastPublished":"Tue, 22 Oct 2013 07:13:40 -0700",          "name":"FMV",           "version":"1.0",            "currentMode":"Design",             "startLocationUpdates":"0",             "promptForPushNotifications":"0",           "allowRotation":"allDevices",           "BT_themes":[{"itemId":"0022CEA6F2649E6360C8C3D", "itemType":"BT_theme", "backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF"}           ],          "BT_tabs":[         ],          "BT_menus":[{"itemId":"2D2C9F150541A76A51C5386", "itemType":"BT_menu", "itemNickname":"Jhonathan" ,"childItems":[{"itemId":"FE26D928B5504FC39ADF8B1", "itemType":"BT_menuItem", "titleText":"Jhonathan Hfghgfhfgh""loadScreenWithItemId":"C7B140DD1E263F760276BEE"}]}           ],          "BT_screens":[{"itemId":"1ACCE0FA6AE0B2F69774E64", "itemType":"BT_screen_menuListSimple", "itemNickname":"Home Screen Menu", "navBarTitleText":"Home","childItems":[]},                 {"itemId":"C7B140DD1E263F760276BEE", "itemType":"BT_screen_customHTML", "itemNickname":"hfghggfhgfhfhfhgfh", "navBarTitleText":"hfghggfhgfhfhfhgfh"}            ]       }       ]   }}
10-23 10:57:34.832: W/ZZ(484): BT_activity_root: application data is not valid JOSN data? You could try to use an online JSON validator. Several good ones exist online. Exiting App.
10-23 10:57:34.851: I/ActivityManager(66): Displayed com.fmvsample/.BT_activity_root: +1s939ms
10-23 10:57:35.331: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 221K, 5% free 8822K/9223K, paused 304ms
10-23 10:57:35.451: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 8918K/9351K, paused 84ms
10-23 10:57:35.471: I/dalvikvm-heap(484): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.961MB for 1155904-byte allocation
10-23 10:57:35.541: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 10047K/10503K, paused 47ms
10-23 10:57:35.621: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 10047K/10503K, paused 4ms+2ms
10-23 10:57:35.791: V/TLINE(484): new: android.text.TextLine@408ee478
10-23 10:57:36.081: V/TLINE(484): new: android.text.TextLine@408af460
10-23 10:57:36.561: D/dalvikvm(144): GC_EXPLICIT freed 78K, 6% free 14616K/15495K, paused 415ms+5ms
10-23 10:57:46.480: D/dalvikvm(213): GC_EXPLICIT freed 169K, 5% free 9150K/9543K, paused 6ms+2ms
10-23 10:57:51.541: D/dalvikvm(258): GC_EXPLICIT freed 206K, 5% free 8721K/9095K, paused 5ms+3ms
10-23 10:57:56.071: D/dalvikvm(66): GREF has increased to 401
10-23 10:57:56.071: I/EventLogService(158): Aggregate from 1382495275770 (log), 1382495275770 (data)
10-23 10:57:56.241: W/EventLogAggregator(158): Unknown tag: system_update
10-23 10:57:56.241: W/EventLogAggregator(158): Unknown tag: system_update_user
10-23 10:58:05.151: D/dalvikvm(281): GC_EXPLICIT freed 10K, 5% free 8632K/9027K, paused 5ms+3ms
10-23 10:58:10.191: D/dalvikvm(335): GC_EXPLICIT freed 367K, 6% free 9253K/9799K, paused 3ms+3ms
10-23 10:58:15.241: D/dalvikvm(399): GC_EXPLICIT freed 59K, 5% free 8638K/9027K, paused 6ms+3ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out the error . "The Json Config generated" by the buzztouch seems not to be a valid 
Json Output.

I try to check it with the use of  [JSON LINT VALIDATOR](http://jsonlint.com/)

to check and see what line would make my jason invalid..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Eclipse is telling you your HOME variable isn't set yet. Here's a guide on it: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Setting_up_the_Home_Directory_on_Windows

Comment: Anything else in the logcat?

Comment: still getting the bold errors given above buddy. what do you think the cause of it. ? havent seen any error highligthed in my eclipse.